# Anime where teenage girl's growth has stopped

Tags: the-friendly-winter

I watched this anime 1-2 years ago but can't remember the name. I would like to watch it again. Judging by the style of the anime it is quite new, I would say no more than 5 years old. The story is about a girl in her teens living with her father. Illness isn't quite the word for it, but her growth has stopped resulting in her looking like a 1st or 2nd grader. She falls in love, but I don't remember how that ends. As she is a teenage girl, she is very cautious of fashion and her main problem is finding clothes that she likes. In the end she start designing clothes for children and people with the same problem as her.

Comment: What kind of anime it looked like? Shoujo, shounen? Does it look similar to another anime?

Comment: Did she player a recorder?

Comment: She doesn't play any instrument. I could remember the age wrong. After thinking about it, I think she's an adult. I think I remember seeing her drink beer.
Can't say that I remember if it looked like another anime.

Comment: If it's any help, the girl had light pink hair, somewhere between her shoulders and waist. She also loves a boy living in the same block as her, but he sees her as a little girl.

Comment: I don't know anime, but I know a full-colored webtoon exactly like that, The Friendly Winter, though I haven't read it to the end, so I don't know the end, and she certainly doesn't have pink hair.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but it is not the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, it is as someone already mentioned, [The Friendly Winter](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=82158).

> A 19 year old girl with a rare growth disorder that leaves her in the body of a small child meets a boy with a mental disorder, who has the mind of a small boy in a 17 year old's body. A Friendly Winter shares with us the endearing story of their day-to-day lives, joys and tribulations.

[image]

You might have mistakenly remembered it as an anime because it is fully coloured. It is actually a Korean Webtoon. Her hair is close enough to be misremembered as pink.

In the end,

> she is proven a capable business woman who runs a children's apparel fashion line.